# What was the name of a movie or a book about a martial arts tournament where the antagonist was a Mongolian fighter?

Tags: story-identification, movie, martial-arts

So far as I remember the name of the movie/book was something like "the golden dragon", all I can remember is how there was a martial arts tournament where the protagonist fights along a friend, and like, the strongest fighter there is a Mongolian fighter, bald with a braid and mustache. He performed Muay Thai (I don't remember if in that tournament there were many different martial artists like a sumo fighter, a kung fu fighter and similar).

The thing is this Mongolian fighter ends up killing the MC's friend wich enrages him.

That's all I can remember.

Comment: What were the science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there do not appear to be any sff elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like Jean-Claude Van Dame's fantastical (e.g., training to fight blind, eye-blinding poisons used during fights, etc.) gladiatorial martial arts send up [*Bloodsport*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodsport_(film)).

Van Dame's character befriends another contestant in an all-martal arts underground no-holds bared tournament, who is paralyzed by a beefy 'Muay Thai' fighter named Chong Li, and this enrages him.

Here's a clip of the final fight: